# How to insert Mysql Data with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I'd like to insert my values from **$_POST** array to my database.

I was looking for some links of this issue, however I haven't found anything.

This is what I'm trying to, I don't know if has some logical or not.

**PHP code**

```
function addData($Connect, $value)
{
  $query = "INSERT INTO Customers VALUES($value)";
  mysqli_query($Connect, $query);
}

$Connect = connectDB();

if($Connect == true)
{
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
  {
    addData($Connect, $value);
  }
}

mysqli_close($Connect);
```

Is there any easy way to do this?, because now this code isn't working.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: yes use prepared statements and look into bulk inserts

Comment: Try bulk insert

Comment: How can I do it?